# JsonPath - selecting a node by filtering on the presence of another node

Tags: json, jsonpath

I'm new to JSON path and can't seem to figure uit how to solve my problem. I would like to have an output of all urls corresponding to 'component1'. For validation I used: http://jsonpath.com

This is my JSON file:

```
{
    "Portfolio":{
        "Website 1":{
            "url":"https://www.website1.com",
            "components":[
                "component1",
                "component2",
                "component3"
            ]
        },
        "Website 2":{
            "url":"https://www.website2.com",
            "components":[
                "component5",
                "component1",
                "component4"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _I would like to have an output of all urls corresponding to 'component1'._ Could you please give us an example of the desired output?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Cássio Mazzochi Molin. In this case the desired output would be "https://www.website1.com" and "https://www.website2.com", since 'component 1' is a component in both situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
$.Portfolio[?(@.components.indexOf('component1') !== -1)].url
```

Mentioned [here](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2), `?()` allows you to run JavaScript code as a filter.

I encourage you to learn exactly what this is doing and make an attempt at the problem yourself next time you post on here.

Comment: One more small question: How do I find the matching master node "Website 1" or "Website 2", corresponding with a given/known url?